# What does NextJS .prepare() actually do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

When running nextjs with a custom server, what does .prepare() called on the next application do?

Answer (score 3):

it does 5 things in this order in an async/await fashion

1. Verify TypeScript Setup
2. load Custom Routes
3. add ExportPathMap to Routes
   Makes `next export` exportPathMap work in development mode.
   So that the user doesn't have to define a custom server reading the exportPathMap
4. start hotReloader
5. records telemetry
   [source code]

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/764edc51b2ba9ae18046804d3ef9adbe0ea703a0/packages/next/server/next-dev-server.ts

Answer (score 1):

It prepare or make the `next.js` code ready to use another server (In their example `express`) for handling SSR.